# Spring Boot - Apache Commons Configuration - How to get properties with the same suffix

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration, configuration-files, apache-commons

I have an `application.properties` file which contains some properties like so:

```
foo.name=Some name
foo.link=https://www.example.com
foo.traits=a trait,another one,and another

...

bar.name=Another name
bar.link=https://www.anotherexample.com
bar.traits=some more traits,and some more,this is getting old
```

How can I get properties which share a similar *suffix*? For example, I want to stuff `foo.name` and `bar.name` into a list/array; similarly with the other properties. I've seen this done with properties that share a prefix, but never a suffix. Is regex the best approach? Or does this library have some function I haven't been able to find?

A note: this needs to be done dynamically; so, if someone were to add another property, say `blah.name`, it would be stuffed into the already existing array which already contains `foo` and `bar.name`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this works out of the box with spring boot. No need for another library.  [reference1](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html), [reference2](http://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot), [reference3](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-configurationproperties-1)

Comment: Spring doesn't support SpEL with `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix=...)` but it does with `@Value`.  Perhaps `@Value` with the expression and injecting it into a map might do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can group property key/value pairs by the key's "suffix" out of the box. I think you need to implement a customization of a [PropertyResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.html) or similar.  Where you would scan all the available properties, pick the ones with the suffix of interest, load the interesting key/value pairs into a Map, and then inject a new dynamic custom Map property back into the [Environment](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/ConfigurableEnvironment.html)

Yes, a regex would be the route I'd take to identify candidate properties.  Something like `^(.*\.)(.*)=(.*)$` where group 1 is the property key prefix, group 2 is the suffix of interest, and group 3 is the property value.